# How to automatically let cmd close Batch File

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, javafx, cmd

So i have a Javafx Maven Projekt which i run with a .bat

```
@echo off
set JLINK_VM_OPTIONS=
set DIR=%~dp0
"%DIR%\java" %JLINK_VM_OPTIONS% -m Main/org.openjfx.Main %*
```

it works but the cmd stays opend and when i close it the project closes aswell
i asked the question [here](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10285) but i didnt got a working answer so i just ask here

btw sorry for my bad english

Comment: There appear to be many duplicate questions related to this.  Here is a google search [batch file close site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=batch+file+close+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=AOaemvLdvOOPyUpGJVZ_Arg7YFDoAE9WOQ:1637612795249&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjPvsKH56z0AhXJPn0KHfZzDpgQrQIoBHoECAoQBQ&biw=3440&bih=1360&dpr=1)

Comment: Please open a command prompt window and run `start /?` to get displayed the usage help of this internal command of `cmd.exe` which can be used to start an executable as separate process from within a batch file on which `cmd.exe` after starting the executable does not wait for self-termination before continuation of processing of the batch file.

Comment: The entire batch file can be optimized to the single command line `@start "JavaFX Maven Project" "%~dp0java.exe" -m Main/org.openjfx.Main %*` which opens a new console window with title `JavaFX Maven Project` and showing `stdout` and `stderr` output in this console window or `@start "" "%~dp0javaw.exe" -m Main/org.openjfx.Main %*` which does not open a console window and so Java application is executed in background, except it opens itself a graphical window.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be uncertain what you need to be kept open, (the sole aim of that batch file is to keep a console window open for visual console feedback) but to answer your request, you need to run your bat file from a cmd prompt, in order to pass parameters otherwise it is mainly redundant.

```
@echo off
set "JLINK_VM_OPTIONS="
set "DIR=%~dp0"
start "" "%DIR%javaw" %JLINK_VM_OPTIONS% -m Main/org.openjfx.Main %*
rem See notes
rem exit
```

Note

javaW will`start` java for windows in non console mode, thus dismissing the batch file. However if you are running from a cmd console that is a separate `exit` that's needed as an extra last line, so try with `rem` first then remove that last `rem` to see any difference.

If you find javaW is not suitable then remove the W at the end.

I have no idea why the source of that file was constructed in such a non windows fashion except the aim seems to be to prefix the run by clearing one and setting one preset environment value, then holding so could be reduced to

```
@Title "Feedback"&set "JLINK_VM_OPTIONS="&set "DIR=%~dp0"&"%DIR%java" -m Main/org.openjfx.Main %*
@echo Done&pause&exit
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from you is like this question [How to automatically close batch program, but keep java program running?](https://superuser.com/questions/1268364/how-to-automatically-close-batch-program-but-keep-java-program-running)
try this if it works.

Comment: Yes but the Problem with that was that then still a cmd shows up but it has the icon of openjdk

Comment: Did you try to use javaw.exe for execution your app ?

Comment: well how to implement it in my batch code cause i use Jlink and it just gave me this batch and dont know how to properly change something

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54134685/16533050 , checks the answer there may help you.